# Multiple SELECT in a single query (hierarchical query)

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a `comments` table with the following content

| id | parent_id | content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | A |
| 2 | NULL | B |
| 3 | NULL | C |
| 4 | 1 | AA |
| 5 | 1 | AB |
| 6 | 1 | AC |
| 7 | 5 | ABA |
| 8 | 5 | ABB |

And I want to select **comment with id = 1**, all of it **children** and **grand children**. Something like this

| id | parent_id | content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | A |
| 4 | 1 | AA |
| 5 | 1 | AB |
| 6 | 1 | AC |
| 7 | 5 | ABA |
| 8 | 5 | ABB |

For now I use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id = 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE parent_id IN (SELECT id FROM comments WHERE id = 1)
UNION
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE parent_id IN (SELECT id FROM comments WHERE parent_id IN (SELECT id FROM comments WHERE id = 1));
```

But this solution can quickly become a huge mess and error prone. Especially when I also want to get the deeper children like **grand grand grand children**

So my question is there any way to make this query simpler? And maybe more performant?

Comment: you need a CTE, and recursive one while at it. it only available on mysql 8+ though. there are other ways to store tree in sql but i forgot what was they called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On MySQL 8+, we can use a recursive CTE:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte (id, parent_id, content) AS (
    SELECT id, parent_id, content FROM comments WHERE id = 1  -- base case
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.id, c.parent_id, c.content                       -- recursive case
    FROM comments c
    INNER JOIN cte t ON c.parent_id = t.id
)

SELECT * FROM cte ORDER BY id;
```